# Even or Odd symmetry

Tags: functions

What type of symmetry does the function $y=\frac{1}{|x|}$ have? 
Specify the intervals over which the function is increasing and the intervals where it is decreasing.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to M.SE. You'll get more appropriate help if you include what you've tried, and what you're struggling with. For example, do you know the definition of even / odd, or increasing / decreasing? Also, please note that many will find the use of the imperative to be rude; please consider editing your question.

Comment: Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=y$

HINT:  what does $f(-x)$ equal?

Let's look at the function, $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.  Now, a function is even if:
$$f(-x)=f(x)$$
and a function is odd if:
$$f(-x)=-f(x)$$
We therefore can see that this function is an odd function, since;
$$f(-x)=\frac{1}{-x}=-\frac{1}{x}=-f(x)$$
Now, the absolute value is defined as
$$|x| = \sqrt{x^2}
$$
With this in mind, let's look at your function;
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}$$
Now what happens when we look at $f(-x)$?
$$f(-x)=\frac{1}{|-x|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(-x)^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\frac{1}{|x|}=f(x)$$
Thus, $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}$ is an even function, symmetric about the y-axis.

Comment: I think it will equal -f(x)

Comment: try the math...you need pencil and paper.  Do you know what the absolute value of a number is?  Have you tried graphing just $\frac{1}{x}$?

Answer (score 0):

Plotting the function is a good way to guess at where the function is going to be increasing or decreasing.  Then you can think about why.

As you increase $x$, what is going to happen to $\frac{1}{|x|}$?  What happens when $x$ approaches (but does not equal!) 0?